# Where to place a collection (cache)?

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections

In an ASP.NET or MVC website project (or any other) where and how a collection of users taken from the database should be placed?

For example, I have a table of users in the database and I want to load it once to the memory as a dictionary of <UserId,User> and perform all the operations on it (and from it to the database).

The collection should be accessible from all of the pages/controllers.
What will be the "Best practices" way to do that?

Should I create a static object called Users that will contained the dictionary and some methods (add, remove, etc.) also as static?

Or should it be a non static object with a static dictionary inside it? and if so, where should it be placed?

Or maybe I am thinking of it in a totally wrong way?

Sorry if my question is not 100% clear, I just gave an example that I think can illustrate the scenario.

It seems to me like a basic issue but I am really confused about the right way of designing it.

Comment: I would likely use a session variable in this example.

Comment: Thanks @HowardRenollet, but in my case I will have to implement it myself and not rely on the session object since I need a different set of behaviors.

Comment: Thanks @DavidKhaykin , Yes, I guess you can say i'm trying to implement a cache mechanism to the database layer, but where should I place the cache object so it will be accessible to all the other classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For our WCF server, we used a static object that contained a table of users and their authorizations.  This worked well and prevented frequent database round-trips on every connection.

The real challenge was ensuring this table was up-to-date when user accounts change.  We implemented a state refresh mechanism.  When someone saves a change to user accounts, the web service detects this change and refreshes its state information.

Note that the .NET Framework 4.0 and higher a [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class built in.

Comment: Thanks @Paul-Williams, I believe i'll go for the MemoryCache, although I'm still curious about the self implementation option. In the case you described, where did you put (declared) the static table? was it on one of the wcf controllers, or did you wrapped it in a designated object?

And if so, where did you put that object so it will be accesable?

Comment: Our WCF service had an application state class that kept our table in memory.  This state class was a Singleton, and it was accessible from anywhere.  The singleton was a static object.  So a state call might look like `ApplicationState.Instance.GetUserAuthorizations(string user)` for example.  Our implementation was more complicated than this example, but it the concept is similar.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, using static objects (`static properties`) in a web application is a horrible idea. Concurrency becomes an issue and weird things with user values changing due to other user input (since a static object is shared across the whole app domain) become apparent.

A static read-only object is an exception to the above.

Probably the best way to handle the scenario in your question is using `caching`. Cache the list, and then rebuild the cache each time after any updates.

If using .net 4.0 or above, take a look at the `System.Runtime.Caching` namespace. It is similar to the old `System.Web.Caching` namespace from earlier versions, but now available to the entire .net framework, and also extensible if needed.

This will take care of "where to put the data".

Then you can implement a Business Logic Layer that handles pulling data from the cache and sending to the UI, communicate with data layer, update the cache after any database updates are performed, etc.

That's how I'd do something like this.

Comment: Thanks @DavidKhaykin, I guess using caching namespace will be the best solution.